# Alamofire migration problems with ParamerterEncoding

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

Having some issues with Alamofire migrating to swift 3. I had this code before working now I'm getting an error. See code below:

```
        let URL = Foundation.URL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL!.appendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

Getting the error on the 'let encoding =' line.

Error:

Type 'ParameterEncoding' has no member 'URL'

Comment: There is lot change with Swift3, you may wanna check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524820/alamofire-type-parameterencoding-has-no-member-url-swift-3

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

Comment: getting extra argument in call