# having some issues with Alamofire migration to swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

Getting some errors from i migrated this project to swift 3 with Alamofire. The second the last line is where I'm getting the error can someone help me to fix this code plz. See error I'm getting below

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct ApiHandler {

    enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
        static let baseURLString = "example.com"
        static let accessToken = "4kjn1kjb3213jkb12k3b12kn321k00"

        case categories(String)
        case assets
        case article(String)
        case top10(String)

        var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
            let (path, parameters) : (String, [String: AnyObject]?) = {
                switch self {
                case .categories(let type):
                    let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)", "content_type": "\(type)"]
                    return ("/entries", params as [String : AnyObject])
                case .assets:
                    let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)"]
                    return ("/assets", params as [String : AnyObject])
                case .article(let type):
                    let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)", "content_type": "\(type)"]
                    return ("/entries", params as [String : AnyObject])
                case .top10(let type):
                    let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)", "content_type": "\(type)"]
                    return ("/entries", params as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            }()
            let URL = Foundation.URL(string: Router.baseURLString)
            let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL!.appendingPathComponent(path))
            let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL //error here line below
            return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error on the second to last line.

Type 'ParameterEncoding' has no member 'URL'

Comment: Alamofire.URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters) . just replace this and use

Comment: already answer available in stack overflow .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524820/alamofire-type-parameterencoding-has-no-member-url-swift-3

Comment: Which Alamofire version are you using? looks like your alamofire is outdated and needs update to be used with swift 3

Comment: @rajatchauhan I am using Alamofire 4

Answer (score 0):

change This code..

```
struct ApiHandler {

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "example.com"
    static let accessToken = "4kjn1kjb3213jkb12k3b12kn321k00"

    case categories(String)
    case assets
    case article(String)
    case top10(String)

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        let (path, parameters) : (String, [String: AnyObject]?) = {
            switch self {
            case .categories(let type):
                let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)", "content_type": "\(type)"]
                return ("/entries", params as [String : AnyObject])
            case .assets:
                let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)"]
                return ("/assets", params as [String : AnyObject])
            case .article(let type):
                let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)", "content_type": "\(type)"]
                return ("/entries", params as [String : AnyObject])
            case .top10(let type):
                let params = ["access_token": "\(Router.accessToken)", "content_type": "\(type)"]
                return ("/entries", params as [String : AnyObject])
            }
        }()
        let URL = Foundation.URL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL!.appendingPathComponent(path))
        return try! Alamofire.URLEncoding.default.encode(URLRequest as! URLRequestConvertible, with: parameters) as! NSMutableURLRequest
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Getting the error type 'ApiHandler.Router does not conform to protocol 'URLRequestConvertible'

Comment: @Slygoth check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524820/alamofire-type-parameterencoding-has-no-member-url-swift-3